# Problem with WndProc() in header file

Tags: c++, winapi, include

I have a LRESULT CALLBACK function in a header file(hook.h) that I both forward declare then define in the file(along with some classes that contain static variables). I then define(implement/create?) the static class variables in the associated .cpp file (hook.cpp).

Finally I include the header file in my stdafx.h file so I can use it in my program.

Because I include the hook.h file twice I get a compilation error that the LRESULT CALLBACK function is defined twice, the error is:

```
stdafx.obj : error LNK2005: "long __stdcall LowLevelKeyboardProc(int,unsigned int,long)" (?LowLevelKeyboardProc@@YGJHIJ@Z) already defined in main.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: static class LowLevelKeyboardHookEx * LowLevelKeyboardHookEx::instance" (?instance@LowLevelKeyboardHookEx@@1PAV1@A)
1>C:\Users\Soribo\Dropbox\C++ Programming\Visual C++ Programming\Key Cataloguer\Release\Key Cataloguer.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

How can I avoid this issue?

My header file:

```
#ifndef KEYBOARDHOOK_H
#define KEYBOARDHOOK_H

#include "stdafx.h"

LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc( int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam );

class MyClass {
    public:
      static std::string instanceStr;
      // further down this class it refers to the function KeyboardProc() thus need for forward declaration
};

LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc( int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
  // implements function
}

#endif
```

My hook.cpp file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "hook.h"

std::string MyClass::instanceStr = "";
```

My stdafx.h file:

```
#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN             // Exclude rarely-used stuff from Windows headers
// Windows Header Files:
#include <windows.h>

// C RunTime Header Files
#include <stdlib.h>

// Application Specific Includes
#include <string>
#include "hook.h"       // I think this is the cause of the error because I include this file twice in compilation which means that the LRESULT function is redefined/reimplemented
```

I have also tried not including the hook.h file in hook.cpp & just including stdafx.h but I get the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your *definition* of KeyboardProc (or is it LowLevelKeyboardProc?) into hook.cpp. That is, move this code from hook.h into hook.cpp

```
LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc( int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
  // implements function
}
```

But leave your "declaration" of KeybaordProc in hook.h.  That is, leave this line inside hook.h:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc( int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam );
```

That way, any other source file can reference KeyboardProc, but only one definition of the function is linked in.

There are some alternative solutions including some "inline" keywords and possibly a pragma/declspec directive to make it work.  Neither seems right for what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

its not a WndProc problem nor a precompiled header problem. Its more of a defining a global function in a header file and including it in more than two source files. What I would say, is to either put the function definition in the source file, or use class static functions.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the implementation of `KeyboardProc` in your `hook.cpp` file. Leave the prototype in the header, but move the code to the `.cpp`.